# guvcview: can not record video

Tags: 16.04, guvcview

I installed [guvcview](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/guvcview), when I try to record a video, it records my voice and one single image. It does not record all the frames (images). How to solve this?

Comment: Don't use guvcview, use cheese: `apt install cheese`.

Comment: Cheese comes by default in Ubuntu 16. I prefer guvcview because it has better options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Change video codec setting

Try changing the video codec guvcview is using to **H.264**. To do that, start `guvcview`, open the *Video* menu, then *Video Codec*, then *MPEG4-AVC (H264)*. With this it should correctly record.